# this plugin works only on page

Tags: plugins

I have a large amount of password-protected posts, all of which are hidden from the average viewer. I’d like a single password entry page to unlock the visibility of all the protected content, as well as a custom landing page after the successful password entry. This plugin seems to do what i’m looking for but only with Pages

can it also work on post and woocomerce products?
i added 'post' in 119 line, but not works

thanks

```
<?php
/*

define( 'SECONDS_TO_STORE_PW', 864000); // 864000 = 10 Days 


 class smartPWPages {

     function smartpwpages_shortcode( $atts ) {
        global $post;

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'label' => __( 'Enter', 'smartpwpages' ),
            'ID' => 'smartPWLogin',
            'parent' => $post->ID,
        ), $atts ) );

        $result =  '<form ID="' . esc_attr( $ID ) . '" method="post" action="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" >' . PHP_EOL;
        if ( isset( $_GET['wrongpw'] ) ) $result .= '<p id="smartPWError">' . __( 'You\'ve entered an invalid password.</p>', 'smartpwpages' ) . PHP_EOL;
        $result .= '    <input class="requiredField" type="password" name="smartPassword" id="smartPassword" value=""/>' . PHP_EOL;
        $result .= '    <input type="hidden" name="smartParent" value="' .  (int) $parent . '" />' . PHP_EOL;
        $result .= '    <input type="hidden" name="smartPWPage_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce( 'smartPWPage' ).'" />' . PHP_EOL;
        $result .= '    <input type="submit" value="' . esc_attr( $label ). '" />' . PHP_EOL;
        $result .= '</form>' . PHP_EOL;
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Password Redirect
     * Decodes the password, stores it in a cookie and redirects the visitor to that page.
     */
     function pw_redirect( $perma, $password ) {
        global $wp_version, $wp_hasher;

        // Version 3.6 introduces a new function
        if ( function_exists( 'wp_unslash' ) ) {
            $cookiePW = wp_unslash( $password );
        } else {
            $cookiePW = stripslashes( $password );
        }

        // Version 3.4 and higher has better security on the pw pages
        if ( version_compare( $wp_version, '3.4', '>=' ) ) {
            if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
                // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
                $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
            }

            // Potentially using a custom hasher, hash the pw
            $cookiePW = $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $cookiePW );
        }       

        $secure = ( 'https' === parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_SCHEME ) );

        // Store password for the length in the constant
        setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $cookiePW, time() + SECONDS_TO_STORE_PW, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );
        wp_safe_redirect( $perma );



        exit();
    }

    /**
     * Process Form
     * Decodes the password submitted on a form, find a page that uses it and redirects the visitor to that page.
     */
    function process_form() {
        global $wp_version, $wp_hasher;
        if ( isset( $_POST[ 'smartPassword' ] ) && isset( $_POST[ 'smartParent' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'smartPWPage_nonce' ], 'smartPWPage' ) ) {
            $parentForm  = (int) $_POST[ 'smartParent' ] ;
            $password = $_POST[ 'smartPassword' ];

            if ( function_exists( 'wp_unslash' ) ) {
                $postPassword = wp_unslash( $password );
            } else {
                $postPassword = stripslashes( $password );
            }

            $args = array(      
                'sort_order' => 'DESC',
                'sort_column' => 'post_date',
                'hierarchical' => 1,
                'post_type' => 'page','post',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );

            if ( function_exists( 'pause_exclude_pages' ) ) pause_exclude_pages();

            $myPages = get_pages( $args );

            if ( function_exists( 'resume_exclude_pages' ) ) resume_exclude_pages();

            // Version 3.4 and higher has better security on the pw pages
            if ( version_compare( $wp_version, '3.4', '>=' ) ) {
                if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
                    // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
                    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php' );
                    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
                }
            }

            foreach( $myPages as $page ) {
                if ( ( $page->post_password == $postPassword ) || ( !empty( $wp_hasher ) && 
                        $wp_hasher->CheckPassword( $page->post_password, $postPassword ) ) ) {
                    $permalink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
                    $this->pw_redirect( $permalink, $postPassword );
                }
            }

            // Nothing more to do here. If we reached here, we've submitted a pw but no match was found. 
            // Allow the page to continue loading, but hack $_GET to indicate the status
            $_GET[ 'wrongpw' ] = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

) );

thanks to everyone can help me

Comment: You are pasting a lot of code, including GNU licenses, that are not relevant to your question. Could you edit the code block and leave only the code that is necessary to ask your question?

Comment: done. it's ok now? le me know